# Has the time for [temporal] ended?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

There is a tag [temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporal) with 246 questions

**Q1.** Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?

**A1.** No, it is a rather ambiguous. It has no wiki and is used for temporal databases, and temporal variables in java, python, R, jpa, spatial to name a few

**Q2.** Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

**A2.**

1. "relating to worldly as opposed to spiritual affairs; secular." No
2. "relating to time." Yes

**Q3.** Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

**A3.** As it is ambiguous, not really.

**Q4.** Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

**A4.** No

Possible tags to use instead are

- [temporal-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporal-database)
- [temporal-difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporal-difference)
- [bi-temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bi-temporal)
- [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time)
- [temporal-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporal-workflow)

Comment: Note that we also have [tag:time], just to make things interesting. The tag wiki there, however, emphasizes measuring time, difference between times, etc., as opposed to things which are limited in time.

Comment: Related: [Tag suggestion for ECMAScript Temporal](/q/405324/4642212).

Comment: Things have recently become even more confused, with the advent of the Temporal workflow engine, which is quickly gaining popularity. The correct tag for that one would be [temporal-workflow], but because [temporal] exists and has no wiki description, users sometime use that tag instead, feeling that this is appropriate.

Comment: So now, we get [javascript]+[temporal] that can either mean a question about the EcmaScript Temporal API, or a question about using the Temporal Workflow TypeScript SDK... Similar goes for [mysql]+[temporal]... Is that a question about using MySQL tables that contains "time-related" data, or is that a question about using the Temporal Workflow engine with a MySQL backend?